# Log4net doesn't log into the server sometimes

Tags: configuration, logging, log4net

Im using log4net to log errors or debugging. But sometimes it just stops logging for some time.

    
    
    
    
    
    
    
      
    
  
Is there anything that Im missing or it is the server problem

Comment: <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/log4net.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="entry:%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline%exception:entry%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender> Here is my config looks like

Answer (score 0):

If it stops momentarily but it later resumes logging and you don't lose any messages, then it probably is that the buffer hasn't been flushed out and written to the file.

Comment: But do you know why it stops for momentarily.
I have other log files on the same server which works but this stops logging.

Comment: It's hard to tell... it could be buffering and the buffer isn't full, so it doesn't flush it. It could also be garbage collection.